# Change option value to selected if same url

Tags: javascript, forms

Good morning,

I have a form

```
<select name="select" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_self')">
<option selected="selected">Select your size</option>
<option value="https://www.webpage.com/01">Size S</option>
<option value="https://www.webpage.com/02">Size M</option>
<option value="https://www.webpage.com/03">Size L</option>
<option value="https://www.webpage.com/04">Size XL</option>
</select>
```

So if people select size S they go to https://www.webpage.html/01 and so on.....
On al the pages i have the same select form, but how can i change the chosen option as selected="selected" using javascript?

So if people select size M, the go to https://www.webpage.com/02 and that the form is displaying size M on this page. So if option value url is the same as the page url it automaticly give the select="selected" to this option.

maybe a dump question, but javascript isnt my best part ;)

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```js
 $("option[value='" + window.location.href.toString() + "']").closest("select").val(window.location.href.toString());
```

It will find the option exactly matching with page url

Answer (score 0):

If url exactly corresponds option values

```
$("selectElementId").val(window.location);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using javascript or jQuery

HTML

```
 <select name="select" id='option' onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_self')">
<option  selected="selected">Select your size</option>
<option value="https://www.webpage.com/01">Size S</option>
<option value="https://www.webpage.com/02">Size M</option>
<option value="https://www.webpage.com/03">Size L</option>
<option value="https://www.webpage.com/04">Size XL</option>
</select>
```

jQuery solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#option').on('change',function(){
        $("#option option:selected").attr('selected','selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with JavaScript only, I would recommend you to do this:

1. add an id attribute to each of the option tags

   ```
   <option id="sizeS" value="https://www.webpage.com/01">Size S</option>
   <option id="sizeM" value="https://www.webpage.com/02">Size M</option>
   ```
2. add a name attribute to the body-tag of each page:
   For example, on the page https:.../01:

   ```
   <body name="S">
   ```
3. add this function to the JavaScript part of each page:

   ```
   function updateForm() {
       var currentSize = document.getElementsByTagName['body'][0].getAttribute('name');
       document.getElementById("size" + currentSize).selected = "selected";
   }
   ```
4. execute the function updateForm() when loading the page. For example, with onload:

   ```
     <body name="M" onload="updateForm()">
   ```

you can also use an event listener with the "DOMContentLoaded" event, click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) for more information: